# if the $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \infty$ then $\lim_{x \to x_0} f'(x) = \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $x_0 ∈\Bbb R$, and let $f$ be a function defined on a neighborhood of
$x_0$. Assume that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $x_0$, except
maybe at $x_0$ itself, and assume that $\lim_{x\to x_0^-} f(x) = +∞$. Then
$\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f'(x) = +∞$?

so ive been trying to come up with a counter example for hours and i cant tell if its true or not anymore...

Comment: Welcome to ME! This time I added mathjax myself, from now on please use it, here is a guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/471959

Comment: Also, given that your function is not even continuous at $x_0$ (having an infinite left limit there), the note "except maybe at $x_0$ itself" is not necessary.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

Take $x_0 = 0$, and consider $f$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}+\sin\frac{1}{x^2}$ (for $x\neq 0$) and $f(0)=0$. It fits the bill, but the derivative has no limit at $0^-$:
$$
f'(x) = -\frac{2}{x^3}\left(1+\cos\frac{1}{x^2}\right), \qquad x\neq 0
$$

Comment: As a follow up to this excellent counterexample, if you know that $f$ has a limit in the extended reals, then this is true as you can use the MVT to find a sequence along which $f$ tends to infinity

Comment: thank you for the counter example! i have a few followup questions if you dont mind?

Comment: how can the limit of the function exist if the limit of sin in this example doesnt exist?

Comment: @Nicole I'll try to answer them (though I may have to leave my laptop some time).

Comment: @Nicole $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = +\infty$ since $\lvert \sin\rvert \leq 1$ but the first term goes to $+\infty$. so you have $\frac{1}{x^2} -1\leq f(x) \leq \frac{1}{x^2} +1$ for $x\neq 0$: use the squeeze theorem to check that the limit at $0$ is indeed $+\infty$.

Comment: @Nicole [This plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bx%5E(-2)+%2B+Sin%5Bx%5E(-2)%5D,+%7Bx,+-0.1,+-0.07%7D%5D) may help: $f$ wiggles, faster and faster (hence $f'$ behaves very strangely) but the amplitude of the wiggles is small, and around a curve (that of $1/x^2$) that goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: @qbert I don't quite get your comment. Here $f$ does have a limit in the extended reals: it's $+\infty$. Did you mean $f'$ where you wrote $f$?

Comment: @ClementC. yes, oops sorry

Comment: One point to add: if $f'$ does have a limit (either finite or $\pm\infty$), then it cannot be finite. So if OP's question had been "...assume $\lim f(x) = +\infty$ and that $\lim f'(x)$ exists; then show that $\lim f'(x) = +\infty$", it would not have been too difficult to show. (I think this is what @qbert's comment was trying to say.)

Comment: @ClementC. thank you for the explanation! one last thing, at the part of the limit of the derivative, how exactly do i show that it doesnt exist?

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes (that's essentially qbert's point above, with the typo removed).

Comment: @Nicole: you can easily find two different sequences $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$, both going to $0^-$, such that $\cos \frac{1}{x_n^2} = -1$ for all $n$ and $\cos \frac{1}{y_n^2} = 1$ for all $n$. This means $f'(x_n) = 0$ for all $n$ (the terms in the parenthesis cancel), while $f'(y_n) \to \infty$.

Comment: @ClementC. I haven't seen sequences yet :\

Comment: @Nicole You can do that with quantifiers to. There exists $A>0$ (indeed, you can take $A=1$ for instance) such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ you can find $x < 0$ such that  $\lvert x\rvert < \varepsilon$ but $f'(x) < A$ (since you can choose $x$ with $f'(x)=0$). This means $f'$ does not have limit $+\infty$ at $0^-$. You can also proceed similarly to show it does not have another limit.

Comment: Intuitively: "no matter how small $\varepsilon>0$ and how big $A>0$, I can give you $x,y\in(-\varepsilon,0)$ such that $f'(x)=0$ but $f'(y) > A$." @Nicole

Comment: i dont quite understand when you can take limits that dont exist but are bounded and show that their composition with other functions must exist, like in this case with sin that DNE but the whole limit does and on the other hand with cos that DNE and the whole limit DNE

Comment: @Nicole Do you see how $x+\cos x$ has limit $+\infty$ when $x\to+\infty$? (despite the fact that $\cos x$ has no limit at $+\infty$)

Comment: @ClementC. yes because cos is bounded so we can prove it exists by squeeze

Comment: @Nicole Yes. Same for $f(x)$ here. But for $f'(x)$, the situation is different, and more similar to something like $x(1+\cos x)$ when $x\to\infty$. sure, the factor $x$ goes to $+\infty$ when $x\to\infty$, *but* $1+\cos x$ cancels out infinitely often along the way.

Comment: (I switched the examples from a limit at $0$ to a limit at $\infty$ in the few comments above for simplicity of exposition, and because it's simpler to write $x$ than $\frac{1}{x^2}$ everywhere)

Comment: @ClementC. so if i were to use the squeeze theorem here i would get different limits on each side making the limit not exist?
and in the counter example case, it doesnt matter that the denominator tends to infinity because of that same reason?

Comment: @Nicole The thing is, you won't we able to use the squeeze theorem for $f'(x)$ here. All you can say is $$0 = \frac{-2}{x^3}(1+(-1)) \leq f'(x) \leq \frac{-2}{x^3}(1+1) = \frac{-4}{x^3}$$ so there is no "squeeze" (only the upper bound goes to $+\infty$). The factor $\frac{-2}{x^3}$ does go to $+\infty$, but is multiplied by a parenthesis factor $$1+\cos\frac{1}{x^2}$$ which is sometimes equal to $2$, sometimes equal to $1$, *and sometimes equal to $0$*. (and everything in between, for that matter)

Comment: So $f'(x)$, when $x<0$ becomes closer and closer to $0$, takes values that are (for some $x$'s) arbitrarily large, but also (for other $x$'s) equal to $0$. @Nicole

Comment: @ClementC. i see. i understand the concept but the thing is i dont understand how to show that it doesnt exist, should i split into one sided limits?

Comment: @Nicole Look at what the definition of a limit says: "there exists a value $\ell$ (possibly $\ell=+\infinity$ to be as general as possible) such that, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, I can take a small enough neighborhood of $x_0$ (there exists $\delta > 0$ ...) such that $f$ is within distance $\varepsilon$ of $\ell$ in that neighborhood." But here, we have that no matter how small the neighborhood of $x_0$ is, there exist values of $x$ for which $f'(x)=0$, and other for which $f'(x) > 10000$ (for instance).

Comment: How can then there be a limit $\ell$? Taking $\varepsilon = 1$ (for instance), that would mean that $\ell$ is both within distance $1$ of $0$ **and** of $10000$...

Comment: (Try to write it formally with the $\varepsilon$/$\delta$ definition of limit and see what that means -- this would help, or at least be a good exercise.)

Comment: got it (: thank you very much! appreciate it

Comment: @Nicole You're welcome!